# get the all the values with latest version-python

Tags: python, max, version

I am looking to extract the list with the latest version from LIST.

`LIST = [base/domain/service1:v1.1.0.10-rc1 ,  base/domain/service1:v1.1.0.10-beta1 ,  base/domain/service1:v1.1.0.8-beta2 , base/domain/service1:v1.1.0.7 ,  base/domain/service2:v1.1.0.10-rc1 , base/domain/service2:v1.1.0.10-beta1 ,  base/domain/service2:v1.1.0.8-beta2 , base/domain/service2:v1.1.0.7 ]`

Output expected (highest version in numerical +alphabatical order):
`max_version = v1.1.0.10-rc1`

I tried sorting the with the version number but the its applying on the entire string using RE

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

if (len(value.split(":v1.")) > 1):

```
    temp_list.append(value.split(":v1.")[1])
    
    max_value = max(sorted(temp_list))
```